# SwiftUI: Resize ColorPicker on macOS

Tags: macos, swiftui, color-picker

I am using a `ColorPicker` in one of my SwiftUI-based macOS apps. In previous versions of macOS `ColorPicker` behaved like a `Color` or `Spacer` View: It filled all the available space. This behaviour changed — it seems to have a fixed default size now:

[image]

**How can I change the size of `ColorPicker` on macOS (SwiftUI)?**

- `.frame()` modifier has no effect
- No luck with adjustments within `GeometryReader`
- `.resizable()` has a visual effect but results in a static (not clickable) view

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it smaller, you can use `scaleEffect`:

```
ColorPicker("", selection: .constant(.red))
    .scaleEffect(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
```

To make the border square-shaped, use `.scaleEffect(x: 0.521739, y: 1)`.

Comment: I have tried `.scaleEffect` but the Picker isn’t clickable afterwards.

Comment: @ixany If you use values smaller than 1, it's clickable on my side. The reason why this works this way is that the tap area doesn't get its size changed.